# Jquery toggle multiple buttons

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have multiple buttons, that get their active css style with a jquery toggle script. But I want to have only one button at a time active. But also, when I re-click an active button, it has to become unactive.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function() {       
        $(this).toggleClass('buttonactive');
    });
});
```

Basicly I need to add a line saying:

`$(all .button except this).removeClass('buttonactive');`

I don't know how. Can someone help me?
Here's a JSFIDDLE with the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/nV5Tu/3/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it like this using [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to toggle current element.. then using [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to filter out current element from having class removed

```
$('.button').click(function() {  
    $('.button').not(this).removeClass('buttonactive'); // remove buttonactive from the others
    $(this).toggleClass('buttonactive'); // toggle current clicked element
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eVy8U/)

Comment: This is the statement that I wanted, didn't know if it existed. But you gotta love jquery/javascript!

Comment: @ThomasCS I waited thinking someone else would get the answer.. but they took too long so I thought I would just answer it :)

Comment: its funny because its exactly the same as my suggested code: $(all .button except this).removeClass('buttonactive'); but then in true jquery.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass("buttonactive")) {       
            $(this).removeClass('buttonactive');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('buttonactive');
        }
        $(".button").removeClass("buttonactive"); // removes all other active classes
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that will make it so that only one button can be pressed at a time, I had this code. But I also need to be able to toggle that one button back to it's original state.

Comment: I have updated my answer. It was not clear from my first read that you wanted to remove all active states *and* disable an existing one if it is already active.

Comment: `$(".button").removeClass("buttonactive");` will remove `buttonactive` class from all buttons.. so it will always go to the `else` part

Comment: Reversed the logic, well spotted :)

Comment: Thanks for you effort, but ryadavilli's answer works and is a lot smaller!

Comment: It might be smaller but it's slightly slower. The not function filters the result-set so it has to iterate over it to apply the filter, then iterate over remaining results to remove the class. My solution checks an existing object which is immediately available, and then only does one iteration on all objects.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know the not function is slow. How much slower are we talking about?

Comment: A tiny margin to be honest. It would depend how many buttons you have. If you have 100s then it may be wise to use this solution instead, especially for slower devices.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you simply remove for all and just add for `this` ?

```
$('.button').click(function() {       
    $('.button').removeClass('buttonactive');    
    $(this).addClass('buttonactive');
});
```

Comment: Yes i've tried that. But then I can't make the button non-active. When it's active a frame is open. When I reclick the buton the frame closes, and it would be intuitive if the button would become unactive too.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need three `document.ready(function()`.. one is enough ...

```
$('.button').click(function() { 
 $(".button").removeClass("buttonactive");  // remove the class for all button on click
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/nV5Tu/4/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I just did some quick copy pasting.

Comment: it wasn't all I wanted, just part of it. I've marked the answer that worked.